# IOS NSArray arrayWithObjects

Tags: ios, arrays, object, block

I try to use a ArrayWithObjects to create a scroll's movement.
And I have a problem, my animation is stopped and repeat at the number nine :/

This is my code :

```
background.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall5.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall6.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall7.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall8.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall9.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall10.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall11.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall12.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall13.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall14.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall15.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall16.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall17.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall18.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall19.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall20.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall21.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall22.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall23.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall24.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_wall.png"], nil];
[background setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
background.animationDuration = 0.3;
[background startAnimating];
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

PS : Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I can't resist an offtopic here: [Number nine... Number nine... Number nine... Number nine...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolution_9)

Comment: Haha good joke ! Your a funny guy. I love It

Comment: Check if the 10th image is not `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `animationDuration` is too small. **You are forcing the object to present all your frame faster than its max possibility**.

From the Apple documentation:

> The time duration is measured in seconds. The default value of this
>   property is equal to the number of images multiplied by 1/30th of a
>   second. Thus, if you had 30 images, the value would be 1 second.

This means that **if you have `24 images`, at least you have to set `0.8` as duration.** (24 / 30).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have tried and this is not working :/ Even if I set 1sec or more duration

Comment: So you have some other problem man because the documentation is clear and if doesn't work and all your code Is right would be that apple UIImageView has a big bug. Improbable.